# What is the quickest way to deploy an ios app to12-15 iPhones in a different state?

Tags: iphone, ios, deployment

My application got ready and client wants to deploy on devices for a presentation in 3 days.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a paid program account yet? If not, that'll be the first day...

Comment: hank god I do have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup the AdHoc distro mode. You can have up to 100 devices via this method.

Comment: Ad Hoc is the way to go.  You need to have a paid developer account.  It gives you an .ipa file you can easily send.  Your client will have to manually install on all the devises either through iTunes or check out the "iPhone configuration tool" from Apple.  Much simpler and easier than iTunes.